# Increasing sequence and subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to prove this statement,

If $x_n$ is an increasing sequence and if some subsequence of it converges, then $x_n$ also converges.

My proof is that suppose $x_{n(k)}$ is the subsequence that converges.  Since $x_n$ is an increasing sequence, we only need to show that it is bounded; then by the Monotone Bounded Theorem, $x_n$ converges.
Since $x_{n(k)}$ converges, then it is bounded say by $M$.
Suppose $x_n^*$ is any arbitrary term of the sequence $x_n$, then since the $x_n$ is increasing, $ x_n^* \leq x_{n(k)} $ for some $ k \in \mathbb{N}$.  Since the subsequence is bounded, then $x_n^* \leq M$ as well.  Thus $x_n$ is bounded and the sequence converges.

Is my proof correct?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you proof is correct.

Comment: The idea to use the monotone convergence theorem is right.  But your write-up is not very clear and your notatoin is really not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self-contained proof (no Monotone Bounded Theorem).

Assume that $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ is the converging subsequence and let $L=\lim_{k\to \infty}x_{n_k}$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $K$ such that $|x_{n_k}-L|<\varepsilon$ for all $k\geq K$.

Now, for any $n\geq n_K$, there is a $J\geq K$ such that $n\leq n_J$. Since $\{x_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ is increasing, it follows that
$$x_{n_K}\leq x_{n} \leq x_{n_J}\leq L$$
and
$$|x_{n}-L|=L-x_{n}\leq L-x_{n_K}=|x_{n_K}-L|<\varepsilon.$$
Hence  $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n}=L$ by definition of limit.